# IIS Express- C# Angular 2 Web Api functionality changes after publish

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have recently published my C# .net core Angular 2 web application to an IIS Server.  However, the Web Api that I am calling is not working correctly.  When I call the Api, a file is supposed to download however, the file does not render correctly.

I am sure that the api is being called as I am not getting a 404 error.  When I run the project on my localhost, it works fine, but on the live site it is not working.

One more thing, when I enter information that should normally cause an error in the web api, it is not throwing me an error like it does in the localhost.  It is as if the api is failing but when it is published to IIS it doesn't recognize the error in the angular observable.  If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening or how I can debug this it would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Please run the WebApi from IIS individually and check the error.
2. Please check the file size while downloading because you need to
   configure in `webconfig` file, if exceed default configuration.
3. Please check in Angular you have subscribe to that observable.
4. If you can give more details on this. It can help us to provide
   more information like specific error and so on.....